# Converter uma lista com dataframes de linhas diferentes em dataframes independentes

Tags: r

Tenho uma lista com 3 dataframes, os quais derivam da função `split`:

```
> split
$`1`
bin group1 group2 missing score1 score2 gender size score3   income          city
  0      1      1      NA      3      2      M    S      4 1605.525 San Francisco
  0      1      2       5      4      4      M    S      5 3463.773  Santa Monica
  0      1      1      NA      4      5      M    L      4 2241.497  Santa Monica

$`2`
bin group1 group2 missing score1 score2 gender size score3   income         city
  1      2      2       7      7      4      M    S      3 2575.955 Santa Monica
  1      2      1       6      6      5      F    L      3 3004.282    Hollywood
  0      2      2      NA      4      6      F    S      2 3458.309    Hollywood

$`3`
bin group1 group2 missing score1 score2 gender size score3   income         city
  0      3      2       4      2      3      M    L      5 1957.105 Santa Monica
  0      3      1      NA      3      6      F    L      3 1786.686    Hollywood
  1      3      2       4      6      7      F    S      4 2065.093    Hollywood
  1      3      1       5      7      8      F    L      7 1561.554    Hollywood
```

Meu objetivo é, com UMA função, transformar cada um desses grupos em dataframes independentes. Tentei algumas funções, mas não obtive êxito.
Em uma delas, por exemplo, apareceu a seguinte mensagem:

> arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apesar da função `createdf` do @Daniel funcionar bem, o R base já tem uma função que faz isso, a função `list2env`.

Criando a mesma lista `a` numa sessão R nova:

```
ls()
#character(0)
```

Agora cria-se a lista `a`.

```
a <- list(cars = cars, mtcars = mtcars, CO2 = CO2)
ls()
#[1] "a"
```

E transformar cada um desses membros da lista em dataframes independentes.

```
list2env(a, envir = .GlobalEnv)
#<environment: R_GlobalEnv>

ls()
#[1] "a"      "cars"   "CO2"    "mtcars"
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode gerar seus dataframes a partir de um for.

```
a <- list(cars = cars, mtcars = mtcars, CO2 = CO2)

for(i in 1:length(a)) { 
  assign(labels(a)[i] , a[[i]])
}
```

Para criar como função, basta adicionar o `environment` global para que as variáveis seja exportadas da função.

```
createdf <- function(a){
  for(i in 1:length(a)) { 
    assign(labels(a)[i] , a[[i]], , envir = .GlobalEnv)
  } 
}

createdf(a)
```